# Access subdomain from domain using php

Tags: php

How can I access subdomain from domain using php, like uploading files etc. without using `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`

Comment: specify the (main) domain in this header, not all (*)

Comment: what do you mean with "access subdomain"? A curl? A include? An (javascript) Api call? What is the problem?

Comment: I need to use the method `move_uploaded_file` and upload it to subdomain. I want to use a subdomain for media.

Comment: is the subdomain on the same server? If yes, then simply move the files to the respective folder.

Comment: Yes, it is on the same server. I have tryed `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]`, but this gives me the root path of main domain. Do you have an example how to do that?

Comment: This totally depends on your folder structure, where the subdomain is linked to, etc. Can't be answered from outside without any information or shown attempt with fitting error messages.

Comment: have a look at `__FILE__` and pathinfo() to find your way to the subdomains path.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple, do not use *(all domain), use specific domain and subdomain

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://api.example.com http://www.example.com');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want to use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. I want something like this `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/uploads/...`